# catch order place after event magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders

I want to catch sales order place after event in Magento 2.

Here is my events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="neo_ordercomment_observer_orderneo" instance="Neo\OrderComment\Observer\Orderneo" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And my observer file is Orderneo file,

```
<?php

namespace Neo\OrderComment\Observer;

class Orderneo implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order= $observer->getData('order');
        $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParams('comment');
        print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;
    }
}
```

But it is not comming to this file,

It should print that last line and then exit. But it is redirecting to Magento's order success page.

Comment: Use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event

Comment: Okay means in events.xml, do I have to replace the event name ?

Comment: Yes `<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">` & `public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;
    }`

Comment: Okay let me check..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with below code in your observer and check,

```
class Orderneo implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     echo $orderId = $order->getId();
     $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');
     print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: So no need to make changes, in events.xml ?

Comment: yes no need to change in event.xml file

Comment: No, still directly order success page is getting called

Comment: You can try with @ankit suggested event, checkout_onepage_controller_success_action and check.

Comment: @DishaSingh, Have you check first your file is calling or not using just echo exit at php file?

Comment: I have added the Controller success event. But now it is redirecting to cart page, after placing order

Comment: just comment line $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment'); and check.

Comment: please share your observer file full code

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar have you successfully getting Massage after placing the order ?
print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;

Comment: if I use exit; page redirects to cart page from order place page instead of showing message or going to success page

Answer (score 9):

It's better use this event instead of `sales_order_save_after` and `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

It will work even site not redirected to success page because of some errors like internet issue, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and `sales_order_save_after` event while after order placing event.

> But you can not use print_r(),die(); and exit(); for debugging. So you
> can use log method for debugging here.
>
> you can use print_r(),die();,exit(); and also log method in
> checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event.

while useing `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event

> Filepath:app\code\Vendorname\Modulename\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="mymodule_controller_success_action" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```

> Filepath:app\code\Vendorname\Modulename\MyObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     echo $orderId = $order->getId();
     print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); 
     exit;
    }

}
```

while using `sales_order_save_after` event

> Filepath:app\code\MyCompany\MyModule\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="mymodule_sales_order_save_after" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Filepath:app\code\MyCompany\MyModule\MyObserver.php

```
  <?php namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer; 
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

    class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface { 


        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('Catched event succssfully');

       }
   }
```

**Edited Date:- 19th Aug, 2021**
"sales_order_save_after" event is best for any custom operation becuase "sales_order_save_after" event fire on every state change(works for Front Side & Admin side both)...

If you wants to do any custom operation at any specific state, then you can easily using this event.

I share detail example below...

If you want to do any operation at only "new" state of sales order then you can do...

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if($order->getState() == "new")
{
     ....
     //do your code as per your need
     ....
}
```

**Please Note that:-**

> we can't debug it in sales_order_save_after event using like echo
> $variable, print_r($variable) or echo
> "console.log(".json_encode($variable).")";
> If you want to debug it then use logger method(print in log file).

See Below Example code

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Catched event succssfully');
```

you can see full example below...

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer; 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

class classname implements ObserverInterface 
{ 
    protected $order;
    protected $_productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    { 
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
    
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        if($order->getState() == "new")
        { 
            $logger->info("OrderId ".$orderId);
            $logger->info($order->getState());

            $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
            foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
                //   $productColl = $product->load($item->getProductId());
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                $QtyOrdered = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                $logger->info("Order Items ".$productId." Total Qty".$QtyOrdered);
            }
            $logger->info('Catched event succssfully'); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how does this work sales_order_save_after?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\LoyalCustomer\Observer\AfterPlaceOrder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\LoyalCustomer\Observer;

use Exception;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InputMismatchException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Executes on order status change
 *
 * Class AfterPlaceOrder
 */
class AfterPlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private CollectionFactory $_orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepository
     */
    private CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $this->updateLoyalAttribute($customerId);
    }

    /**
     * Update the Attribute thorugh customer Id
     *
     * @param $customerId
     * @throws InputException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws InputMismatchException
     */
    private function updateLoyalAttribute($customerId)
    {
        $collection = $this->countOrders($customerId);
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        if (count($collection) > 2) {
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('loyal_customer', true);
        } else {
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('loyal_customer', false);
        }
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
    }

    /**
     * Count the order
     *
     * @param $customerId
     * @return Collection
     */
    private function countOrders($customerId)
    {
        return $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create($customerId)
            ->addFieldToSelect('status')
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Complete');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\LoyalCustomer\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InputMismatchException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
/**
 * Change the behaviour of customer
 *
 * Class AfterPlaceOrder
 */
class AfterPlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private CollectionFactory $orderCollection;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private Session $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $orderCollection
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $orderCollection,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->orderCollection = $orderCollection;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface=$customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->customerSession=$customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Update the loyal customer attribute after placing the order 2 and more
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @throws InputException
     * @throws InputMismatchException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $orderCollection = $this->orderCollection->create()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
        if ($orderCollection->count() >= 2) {
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('loyal_customer', true);
        } else {
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('loyal_customer', false);
        }
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
    }
}
```