# Magento 2 - Place an order without sending email

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-gateway, order-email

I'm using the following code to place an order programmatically in Magento 2:

```
    // Configure the quote
    $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
    $quote->setPaymentMethod('custom_gateway');
    $quote->save();

    // Set the payment method
    $payment = $quote->getPayment();
    $payment->importData(['method' => 'custom_gateway']);

    // Update the quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    // Place the order
    $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

This code is creating the order as expected, but is also sending an email to the shopper.

I would like to send the confirmation email at a later stage in the process, only when the payment has been confirmed.

How can I place an order without notifying the customer?

Comment: Seem that you're implementing the online payment?

Comment: Did you find a solution at last? :(

Answer (score 1):

We can set the flag for order: `$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false)`

We can see some good examples for online payments:

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Observer/Webapi/SubmitObserver.php

vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflowlink.php
```

Comment: If the placeOrder() function sends an email, I don't see how I can set the flag after the order has been created. I have just tried the following and the email is still sent:           $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
         $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);

Comment: It seems that once the order has been placed, it's too late to set the flag. Could you please suggest a way to create an order where your suggestion would be usable?

Comment: I think we can try with plugin: `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::place()`. Should use `afterPlace()` plugin. We can set `$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false)`.

Comment: I am not sure about how to implement this. Would you please have a short example?

Comment: in the Payflow extension you mention, this is what happens: $order = $payment->getOrder(); $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false); So basically the order already exists, that's why you can set a flag. In my case, the order is created from a quote so you can't set the flag before the order is created. Is there any way to disable email notification at the quote level for example?

Comment: Honestly, it's daunting that it's so difficult to disable email for a single order in such a powerful platform. I just don't understand how this wouldn't be possible. Same, deleting an order in M2 is a task for titans. Why so much hassle?

Comment: `$this->cartManagement->placeOrder($quote->getId());` --> ` `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::placeOrder()` --> `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::submitQuote()` has `$order = $this->orderManagement->place($order);`

Comment: Tomorrow, I will update my answer properly.

Comment: Hello Khoa, have you had a chance to look more into this?

Comment: This is great. I used it inside a 'sales_order_place_after' observer. You can see how to create a sales order observer here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166695/catch-order-place-after-event-magento2

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use this:

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement;
...
// Create order from quote
$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

QuoteManagement will not send an order until you call

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;
...

// Send the email when desired
$this->orderSender->send($order);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this and I have came up with this:

1. Most solutions out there is doing something like this:

```
$cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();
...
...
$orderId = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

Which is the easiest solution in my opinion.

But this method triggers an observer:

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_success
```

Which is responsible for sending the emails.

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Observer/SubmitObserver.php
```

This means you can't do $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false) before the emails is sent at least once.

For this what I did was :

1. When creating the cart do:

`$cart->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);`

2. Make a new observer that will be executed before Quote module:

```
    <sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
    </sequence>
```

3. On the observer do:

```
    if($quote->getCanSendNewEmailFlag() == false){
    $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
```

With this now you can set the `setCanSendNewEmailFlag` before sending an email.

Answer (score 0):

i checked your code you are using

`$this->cartManagement->placeOrder($quote->getId());`

the simple workaround for your placeOrder function is. Magento is sending the email by observing this `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success` dispatch event and  `vendor/magento/module-quote/Observer/SubmitObserver.php` this file is observing that event and will trigger mail based on the condition.

You can observe `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` this dispatch event to change the order can send new email flag to false like this `$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);`

`etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Order\ChangeEmailFlag" name="events_change_flag"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

In ChangeEmailFlag.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Order;
  
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ChangeEmailFlag implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    protected $quoteRepository;

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order= $observer->getData('order');
            
            if(//your condition)
            {
                $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
            }
           
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Tested in Magento2.4.6 working perfect.

Please upvote if it is useful.

Answer (score -1):

have you checked this: `admin->Stores->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails->Order` and set **Enabled** as **no**

now check !!

Comment: Thank you for the info. Is there no way to do that for a single order without impacting the global configuration?

Comment: Basically I am working on a custom payment gateway. If I do what you suggest from a global config, what happens to other payment gateways that need this on?