# Email notification for cancelled order

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, magento2.1.6

Hi is it also possible to get email notification for cancelled orders?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always write your own module that will do that.

You will need few ingredients for that:

1. Have an observer that listens on the `sales_order_save_after` event.

   This link explains it well

   [catch order place after event magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166695/catch-order-place-after-event-magento2)

   In this observer you will get the order object by
   `$order= $observer->getData('order');` and you could check if the new status is `canceled`
2. If condition from point 1 above is true you can proceed to send an email programatically.
   This link offers good idea of how to do that

   [How to send mail programmaticlly in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132391/how-to-send-mail-programmaticlly-in-magento2)

Comment: I cannot guarantee that it will be easy to directly copy and use them. But I think it will give you a good idea. And if you somehow get stuck, well, just add a new question here :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate functionality for sending the email on order cancellation.

You can use the `order_cancel_after` event for writing your email function.

You can get the order details using the order object as given below

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderCancellationEmail implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getData('order');
        // Write your email function here
    }
}
```