# get all order information from checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Tags: checkout, event-observer, magento2.4

I have an Observer for `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and I would like to load ALL order information inside this observer: order items, options, customer info.

I have tried a number of different things, I will include them (commmented out) below.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Reports\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ReportObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    /*
    //doesn't work
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     echo $orderId = $order->getId();
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($order);
     echo "</pre>";
     */

     /*
     //doesn't work
     $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
      $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
      $orderid=$order->getEntityId();
      $custLastName= $orders->getCustomerLastname();
      $custFirsrName= $orders->getCustomerFirstname();
      $ipaddress=$order->getRemoteIp();
      $customer_email=$order->getCustomerEmail();
      $customerid=$order->getCustomerId();

      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($order);
      echo "</pre>";
      */

      /*
      //doesn't work
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
      echo "<pre>";
      //print_r($order);
      echo "</pre>";
      echo "<hr>";
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r( $order->getAllItems() );
      echo "</pre>";
      */

      /*
      //doesn't work
     $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
     //$order = $this->_order->get($order_ids);
     $order = $this->order->get($order_ids);
     $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
     $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
     foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
     {
           $item->getName();
           $item->getSku();
           echo $item->getName();
     }
     */

     $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
     echo $orderId = $orderIds[0];
     // can do sql queries here
     echo "<hr>";

     //print_r("order done");
     exit;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Reports\Observer;

class ReportObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  
    protected $_orderFactory;    
    
    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    /**
     * This is the method that fires when the event runs.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer )
    {               
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        
        if (count($orderIds)) {
            $orderId = $orderIds[0];            
            $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
            $orderid=$order->getEntityId();
            $custLastName= $order->getCustomerLastname();
            $custFirsrName= $order->getCustomerFirstname();
            $ipaddress=$order->getRemoteIp();
            $customer_email=$order->getCustomerEmail();
            $customerid=$order->getCustomerId();            
            $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
            foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
             {
                //add code for fetch order item info here.
             }

             //For Full order data info remove comment below code and check the generated log file.
            // $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/order_data_'.date('my').'.log');
            // $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            // $logger->addWriter($writer);
            // $logger->info('---------- Full Order data ---------');
            // $logger->info(print_r($order->getData(), true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @jitendra.

I just tried this, and as a quick test I added this:
`//add code for fetch order item info here.
echo "<pre>";
print_r($item);
echo "</pre>";`

unfortunately it does not work... it seems like $order is just not available for some reason. it's empty.

Comment: can you uncomment logger code and comment out other code and check the $order->getData() in log file ?

Comment: Please adding above code please run below command. php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: both of those things show that the order object is empty. no data in there.

Comment: Can you refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166695/catch-order-place-after-event-magento2

Comment: the accepted answer at that links works ONLY for the ID.  I am unable to load any other order information.  my plan now is to just write my own SQL to retrieve it... not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, Can you confirm below things regarding your implementation.
1] Whether your event trigger and above mentioned log file generated ?
2] For cross verify you can check this link which fulfill your requirement. check your events.xml file for frontend or global. https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-event-observer/

Answer (score 0):

**Please Refer Below Code**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Reports\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ReportObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    
    protected $order;  
  
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    )
    {
        $this->order = $order;    
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $orderId =$order->getId();  
      try {
    
        $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
        
        
        $orderid=$order->getEntityId();
        $custLastName= $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $custFirsrName= $order->getCustomerFirstname();
        $ipaddress=$order->getRemoteIp();
        $customer_email=$order->getCustomerEmail();
        $customerid=$order->getCustomerId();
        
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($order->debug());
        echo "</pre>";
        die("exit");
      }catch (\Exception $e) {          
          $e->getMessage();
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: this gives an interesting error, I will look in to this:
`Argument 1 passed to Company\Reports\Observer\ReportObserver::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order, instance of Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory given,`

Answer (score 0):

> **ALL order information inside this observer:**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\ShoppingCart" name="shopping_cart_order_success"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Observer**

**ShoppingCart.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ShoppingCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $cart;
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* check  order id */
        $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
        if (is_array($orderIds)) {
            foreach ($orderIds as $orderIdKey => $orderIdVal) {
                $orderData = $this->orderRepository->get($orderIdVal);
                print_r($orderData->debug());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***